# ASP - Removing Double quotes from a string

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

I have a ASP Page and it has so many date variables.

```
myvariable = FormatParameter("EndDate")
```

EndDate is "10/01/2001"

How can I remove the double quotes from the date variable? so that it can be 10/01/2001.

I can do this in .NET but couldn't find a way to do it in ASP.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
myvariable = Replace(FormatParameter("EndDate"), """", "")
```

Comment: That's because strings are not objects in vbscript, and `Replace` is just a function.

Comment: when I do the replace and response.write it still displays the double quotes. I think I am back to where I started.

Comment: @kalls, that's very strange. The `Replace` should be replacing all double quotes, without exceptions. Maybe something is adding the quotes later on your code?

Comment: Thanks @bfavaretto I am looking into this.

Comment: @kalls - two things are coming to mind: if you see the value with quotes using a debugger it just means it's of type string, those quotes are not really part of the value. Second option - maybe they're not really quotes but some other characters. Go [here](http://easycalculation.com/ascii-hex.php) type the value exactly as you see it (in Response.Write) and if double quotes, you should get ASCII 34 - for example `"hello"` will bring `34 104 101 108 108 111 34`